# Did the reputation cap change recently?

Tags: bug, daily-reputation-limit

I've reached the reputation cap 1 hour ago (200), but a minute ago I received an upvote for an answer which is not an accepted one and now I have 210. Is this a bug or the rep cap was changed recently?

[image]

Comment: You have 2 accepted answers which are not counted towards the rep-cap.

Comment: But I already had 200 when I received an upvote for an answer which was not accepted.

Comment: here we go again.

Answer (score 9):

You have two accepted answers, totaling in 30 rep **that is not counted towards the repcap**.

Reputation for accepted answers, accepting answers, getting bounties and the association bonus are all exempt from the rep cap.

More information is in [how does reputation work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)?

Comment: So if I get for example 20 upvotes for a question and reach 200 then the OP accepts it I can get another 200 with an other question?

Comment: @AdamArold You can get a max of 200 rep on upvotes a day, you can go over the 200 with accepts/bounties.

Comment: @AdamArold - huh? No. You get 200 for the upvotes, another 15 for the accept and the other upvotes count for nothing as you have rep capped from upvotes already.

Comment: Oh I understand now. So the 200 cap is only for upvotes after that only accepts/bounties count.

Comment: @AdamArold - pretty much. There is also reputation for approved suggested edits, which also counts towards the rep cap (a +2 per approved edit).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation.